# Multiple Jpanels in card layout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a project in which I use quiz based questions in Java swings. I do not know which layout to use and how many panels.frames to use. 
I do not know if I have 100 questions and Next button will proceed to next question, how many Panels.frames I will need and which layout I will use in this case. 
Please some body help me here.

Comment: It sounds like the place to begin is planning. There is no perfect solution, but all engineering projects begin with choices. How would you like to lay it out? How would you like to move to the next question? Do you want multiple windows, or just one cohesive, easy to program window? Once those have been answered, you can begin researching *how* to achieve those design goals.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a CardLayout for each Question.

Instead you have a single panel that can display the data from your question.

Then you have an ArrayList containing your Question Objects.

The "Next" button would simply get the next Question from the ArrayList and refresh the data on your panel.

Comment: Unless question _types_ vary, e.g. true-false vs. multiple-guess vs. board-style, etc.

Comment: @trashgod, good point, you would need one panel for each type of question.

Comment: My questions are not hard coded to put it in ArrayList, rather they are inside in Protege ontology and have to import it in Java (Jena API) code. If you dont have knowledge about Protege, consider it like database which needs to be imported through SQL like queries(SPARQL).

Comment: @KumarRohit so the data is in a fixed format. You query the database and create your `Question` objects. We can't help you any more than this. Only you know the format of your data.

Comment: @camickr, Thanks , actually the data is in OWL format(Semantic web) but getting data will not be problem for me, I hope.. I have problem with UI as discussed because I dont know how to set the first UI page and what will happen when Next button is clicked i-e how to refresh the Panels with new questions etc

Comment: @KumarRohit, `I dont know how to set the first UI page and what will happen when Next but` - how do you set data for any page? This is no different. You get the data from somewhere then you add the data to a Swing component. For example, If you use a JLabel you just use the setText() method. First create your UI with hardcoded data. Then create a method to replace the hard coded data with data from somewhere else.

Comment: @camickr, thanks for your time and useful suggestions.Let me begin it now.

Comment: @camickr, trashgod, are you sure the card layout is not using here in this  scenario. Because I read a tutorial on quiz type game (though his questions are hardcoded), he used Box layout and cardlayout. All of his guiz  questions have one label for question, four radiobuttons and Next  Button to switch to another question. Frankly speaking quite confuse with this layout scenes.

Comment: @KumarRohit, `All of his guiz questions have one label for question, four radiobuttons and Next Button to switch to another question.` - and that is what was suggested here. You create a form to hold the questions/answers. We only suggested multiple different panels if you have different types of questions. Again reread Trashgod's comment.

Comment: @camickr, thanks a lot. Since I am very fresh to programming, I am confuse. I have 15 this type of questions(4 radio buttons) so I need one Jpanel for it, 10 true/false questions, need separate panel for it and 10 fill the blanks question, another panel for this.so in this case card layout will be used in which panel?

Comment: @KumarRohit, the CardLayout is used on the parent panel. Then you add the 3 child panels to the parent. You then show the appropriate panel for the given question. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for an example to get you started.